# Python - How to print the message inside ValidationError

Tags: python, exception, printing, except

I would like to know how to print the string written when raising an exception.

For example if I use

```
raise ValidationError("RANDOM TEXT HERE");
```

How can I retreive "RANDOM TEXT HERE" from within the except section.

```
try:
  ...
except ValidationError:
  ...
  // something like Java's ex.getMessage();
  .....
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried looking at the exception object's attributes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you bind the exception to a variable, then you could get its string representation with `str(exception_variable)`.

Namely:

```
try:
  ...
except ValidationError as e:
  print str(e)
```

**Edit: Changed `msg` to `message`**

**Second edit: Realized that exceptions are inconsistent between storing messages in `msg` vs `message`. `str(exception)` seems to be the most consistent.**

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old question, but I also faced same issue and I write my solution for anyone needs in future.

When I use **`e`** variable, it gave me a `list`, so I used **`e.message`**

```html
try:
  ...
except ValidationError as e:
  print e.message
```